# Flash Player & Xvfb: Application crashed with an unhandled SIGSEGV

Tags: centos, flash, xvfb

I'm using Xvfb to get screenshots of flash stuff, however when I use Xvfb to do this, right after flash is started in Xvfb, the error "Application crashed with an unhandled SIGSEGV" is output.

Any ideas?

When I run flash outside of Xvfb it doesn't give any abnormal errors (it complains there's no display).

I'm using CentOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

It had to do with some dependencies. Note it needs 32-bit ones.

Needed these:

yum install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb libX11.i386 libXext.i386 libXt.i386 libXcursor.i386 gtk2.i386